# How can the Witch Archetype gain access to Hex Cantrips?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, archetype, witch

I have a martial character who, while reasonably intelligent, is not nearly as brilliant as they think they are.  It seems appropriate for their free archetype to be Witch with the Rune Patron, as they would want the extra knowledge.  I am particularly drawn to the Hex Cantrip *Discern Secrets*.

When I look at the Archetype, however, I see

> Choose a patron; you gain a familiar with two common cantrips of your choice from your chosen patron's tradition, but aside from the tradition, you don't gain any other effects the patron would usually grant.

This implies that you don't get access to the patron Hex Cantrip as part of the Archetype. I also don't see an archetype feat that would give access to the Hex cantrip, either.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8):

### They Can't

You're correct that there's no way for a character with the witch archetype to gain a patron's hex cantrip. Unfortunately this means only characters with the witch class can learn to use those patron hex cantrips.

Other class archetypes generally have some way to gain non-feat mechanics like with the bard's [Inspirational Performance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=682). Hex cantrips may be considered too powerful or impactful for any character to pick up with just an archetype.